# function for weighted least squares estimates

Tags: r, least-squares

Does R have a function for weighted least squares?  Specifically, I am looking for something that computes intercept and slope.

**Data sets**

1. 1 3 5 7 9 11 14 17 19 25 29
2. 17 31 19 27 31 62 58 35 29 21 18
3. 102153 104123 96564 125565 132255 115454 114555 132255 129564 126455 124578

The dependent variable is dataset 3 and dataset 1 and 2 are the independent variables.

Comment: From your comments it doesn't sound like you really want weighted least squares but instead multiple regression.  Care to revise your question appropriately?

Comment: It's still not clear to me (having read the answers and comments below) how weights come into the picture.

Comment: More about least squares [here](http://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd141.htm) and [here](http://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd143.htm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, of course, there is a `weights=` option to `lm()`, the basic linear model fitting function.  Quick example:

```
R> df <- data.frame(x=1:10)
R> lm(x ~ 1, data=df)            ## i.e. the same as mean(df$x)

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ 1, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
        5.5  

R> lm(x ~ 1, data=df, weights=seq(0.1, 1.0, by=0.1))

Call:
lm(formula = x ~ 1, data = df, weights = seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
          7  

R>
```

so by weighing later observations more heavily the mean of the sequence 1 to 10 moves from 5.5 to 7.

Comment: not sure if i follow. if i have 3 data sets how would i estimate intercept and slops. data set 1) :1 3 5 7 9 11 14 17 19 25 29 data set 2:17 31 19 27 31 62 58 35 29 21 18 dataset 3:102153 104123 96564 125565 132255 115454 114555 132255 129564 126455 124578   the dependent variable is dataset 3 and dataset 1 and 2 are the independent variables

Comment: Now we don't follow.  What are the weights you want to use?

Comment: whichever weights predict Y the best.

Comment: Then it doesn't sound like you want weighted least squares after all.

Comment: @Dirk: can you elaborate what the `"x ~ 1"` actually mean? Chase's reply infers that things such as `"y ~ x1 + x2"` are like "dependent vars VS independent vars" or am I over-interpreting?

Comment: @hhh: `x~1` is an intercept-only regression model. These formulae are the basis of regression modeling in R: if you need to do regression you should start by reading the relevant section in the Introduction to R (and possibly Faraway's linear modeling book draft in the contributed documents section on the R web site) -- also see the link in Chase's answer

Answer (score 5):

First, create your datasets. I'm putting them into a single data.frame but this is not strictly necessary.

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,3,5,7,9,11,14,17,19,25, 29)
                  , x2 = c(17, 31, 19, 27, 31, 62, 58, 35, 29, 21, 18)
                  , y  = c(102153, 104123, 96564, 125565, 132255, 115454
                           , 114555, 132255, 129564, 126455, 124578)
                  )
```

Second, estimate the model:

```
> lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
  104246.37       906.91        85.76
```

Third, add your weights as necessary following @Dirk's suggestions.

Fourth and most importantly - read through a tutorial or two on regression in R. Google turns this up as a top hit: http://www.jeremymiles.co.uk/regressionbook/extras/appendix2/R/

Comment: @RyanB - I would add your data to your questions so that it is all in one place. Also, if this answer your question, clicking the check mark to "accept" it will let others in the future know that this was helpful to you.

Comment: @RyanB Then please do note the terminology used by @Chase and @Aaron - what you are doing is not a weight least squares (WLS) unless you supply some weights. What @Chase shows is just ordinary least squares. @Dirk's Answer shows you how to start using WLS with the `lm()` function.

Comment: Yes Gavin, the combination of the two responses answers my question.

Comment: what about if you have a model with random constants before the variables `x1` and `x2` like `"y ~ \beta_{1} x1 + \beta_{2} x2+error"` where you assume that the error does not correlate with `x1` and `x2`?

Answer (score 0):

Just another take on this.  You can create a weight matrix first. For example:

```
samplevar = var(ydata)

M = diag(40,1/samplevar)
```

At this point M is a 40x40 diagonal matrix.  You can convert to a vector by applying diag to M:

```
M_vector = diag(M)
```

Then use this in `lm` :

```
   lm ( YXDATAFRAME, weights=M_vector)
```