# least square percentage regression

Tags: r, regression

Is there an R package implementing least square percentage regression. A paper on this is found on this link:

https://uhra.herts.ac.uk/dspace/bitstream/2299/965/1/S64.pdf

Any help or direction would be helpful.

Comment: One way to think about this is weighted least-squares fitting, where the weights are inverse squares of the observations.

Comment: This previous SO question, [r - function for weighted least squares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375650/function-for-weighted-least-squares-estimates), may be helpful.