# Running percentage least squares regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I am interested in running a percentage least squares regression, rather than ordinary least squares regression in R. This could also be referred to as a linear model with multiplicative error. One question has been asked before regarding percentage least squares on this site, and responders suggested looking into weighted regression, with one possibility being weighting each observation by the inverse square of its X value.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/15275236/least-square-percentage-regression](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/15275236/least-square-percentage-regression)

However, this assumes I know how much each observation should be weighted a priori. I don't. I don't know if the percent error is 1%, 10%, 15%, etc. What I want is a model fit as

```
y= b1*x + e
```

where the error term is modeled as:

```
e= b2*x
```

b2 would be the percentage error that needs to be minimized in the regression model. I have not been able to find any package or any code to fit a model of this type for R. any feedback on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this not equivalent to using a log-transform of y and proceeding with ordinary least squares regression?  To get back to the untransformed y, you would exponentiate the RHS, resulting in multiplicative terms and errors.

Comment: @zkurtz log transformation assumes the relationship takes the form of y=e^x, and therefore the effect size from the back transformation will be diminished if the relationship is truly linear. Log transformation may be suitable for determining significance, but not effect size. I'd prefer to model the data as they are in reality, rather than transform to deal with non-normal residuals at the cost of estimating the proper effect size.

Comment: To be more explicit, a log transformation would make the error distribution normal and deal with heteroscedasticity of this pattern so that it could be handled in a OLS framework. Furthermore, it may be defensible to take the effect size from the untransformed model in this situation. However, what I'd prefer to do is run one model that handles it all. This would be achieved by running a percentage least squares regression, rather than an ordinary least squares regression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean percentage regression as defined by Tofallis [(2009)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1406472).

Using his example:

```
Sales <- c(6375,11626,14655,21869,26408,32406,35108,40295,70762,80553,95294,101314,116141,122316,141650,175026,230614,293543)
Expenses <- c(62.5,92.9,178.3,258.4,494.7,1083,1620.6,421.7,509.2,6620.1,3918.6,1595.3,6107.5,4454.1,3163.8,13210.7,1703.8,9528.2)
```

> If we apply ordinary least squares with sales as the dependent
>   variable we obtain the model    Sales = 43942 + 15.00 R&D with
>   p-values of 0.03 and 0.0015 for the intercept and slope respectively.

```
fit1 <- lm(Sales ~ Expenses)
summary(fit1)
#                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept)   43941.705  18493.079   2.376  0.03033 * 
#   Expenses       14.994      3.915   3.830  0.00148 **
```

> If we do this and carry out ordinary least squares we obtain the
>   model:     Ln(Sales) = 10.341 + 0.000198 R&D with p-values of 0.002
>   for the slope and essentially zero for the intercept.

```
fit2 <- lm(log(Sales) ~ Expenses)  
summary(fit2)
#                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   1.034e+01  2.535e-01  40.793  < 2e-16 ***
#   Expenses    1.982e-04  5.366e-05   3.694  0.00197 **
```

> Finally, we turn to the approach presented in this paper, minimising
>   the squared percentage residuals. The resulting model is found to be,
>   after transforming back:   Sales = 8817 + 17.88 R&D with p-values of
>   0.002 and 5×10-5  for the slope and intercept respectively.

```
fit3 <- lm(Sales ~ Expenses, weights = 1/Sales^2)
summary(fit3)
#               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)   8816.553   2421.644   3.641   0.0022 ** 
#   Expenses      17.880      3.236   5.525 4.61e-05 ***
```

So, in the end, this is weighted regression.

To confirm this, we can also use numeric optimization:

```
resfun <- function(par) {
  sum((Sales - par[[1]]*Expenses - par[[2]])^2 / Sales^2)
}

optim(c(10,1000), resfun)
# $par
# [1]   17.87838 8816.44304

optim(c(10,1000), resfun, method="BFGS")
# $par
# [1]   17.97975 8575.71156
```

(Different optimizers will give slightly different results.)

Comment: I do mean percentage regression as defined by Tofallis 2009. Thank you for attaching the reference. Your response and the original paper are both very clear. I do have one problem though- the Tofallis paper you linked suggests weighting by (1/y), while you recommend weighting by (1/y^2). y is "Sales" in your example. Why do you choose to weight by (1/y^2) rather than (1/y) as recommended in the source? To me me weighting by the inverse square rather than just the inverse would give larger observations even less weight, which is not something I want to do!

Comment: @colin Weighting with 1/y^2 (using function `lm`) means that the squared residuals are multiplied with the weights (i.e., the residuals are multiplied with 1/y). At a quick glance that's in agreement with the reference. If you disagree, please point out the relevant part of the paper. You are free to use any weights you want, if that improves the model.

Comment: thank you. I have decided to weight with 1/y, rather than 1/y^2. In the manuscript the description is in the "Derivation of formulae for the coefficients" section, starts at the bottom of page 3, goes on to page 4.

To follow up, when checking normality I believe it is correct in this situations to look at the qqnorm plot of the model residuals divided by the square root of the y values, and same should be done for the residuals vs. fitted values?

Comment: @colin AFAIU they divide the residuals by `y`. Since my code divides the squared residuals by `y^2`, it should be the same. However, generic advice for weighted regression applies here. Study residual and leverage plots and compare AIC.

Comment: @colin: I think weights =(1/y^2) works as in this example. Fitted value (Residual = 40% of Fitted): 10 (4), r^2[1/y] 16/10 = 1.6, r^2[1/y^2] 16/100 = 0.16; 20 (8), r^2[1/y] 64/20 = 3.2, r^2[1/y^2] 64/400 = 0.16. If your model minimizes Residuals^2 and you want all Residuals of z% of y to have equal weight (in my example, 40%), then weights=(1/y^2).

Comment: Forgot to add: Note that if your y is already log-transformed, then standard OLS performs percentage least squared (log subtraction = normal division): exp(a+residual)/exp(a) = exp(b+residual)/exp(b)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `gls` function in the `nlme` package, along with one of the `varClasses` such as `varIdent` or `varPower`.

Possibly a model like:

```
gls( y ~ x, data=mydata, weights=varPower(form= ~x) )
```